# How to list only the .log files with today's date in their name and ERROR: in their body in UNIX

Tags: date, unix, text-processing

I'm using this code to get all `.log` files with `ERROR:` in their body (not Name). However, I couldn't figure a way to pick only the files with today's name in their name.

```
ls -1 /fbrms01/dev/Logs/*.log | xargs grep -l "ERROR:"
```

Gives this output:

```
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_Authorized_Inventory_End_2013.03.27_17.06.40.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_Authorized_Inventory_End_2013.03.27_18.03.05.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_Authorized_Inventory_End_2013.03.27_20.54.34.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_CreateFormat_2013.03.18_08.27.49.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_CreateFormat_2013.03.18_17.21.31.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_CreateFormat_2013.03.28_15.30.41.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_ExtReservationDetail_2013.03.15_13.06.26.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_Report_Master_2013.03.18_09.53.38.log
/fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_Throughput_Capacity_2013.03.28_16.49.05.log
```

Date in the name of the files are in `_yyyy.mm.dd_` format. Is there any way to get today's date in unix and compare it with name and pull only those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get today's date with

```
TODAY=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d")
```

You find name of files with certain pattern with:

```
grep -l ERROR /your/dir/*
```

as `-l` pattern will show the files matching the pattern.

So you can even directly grep files which have `$TODAY` in their name:

```
grep -l ERROR /fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_Authorized_Inventory_End_$TODAY*.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
grep -l "ERROR:" `ls -1 /fbrms01/dev/Logs/*.log | grep "\`date +"%Y.%m.%d"\`"`
```